# Asus Republic of Gamers 0.75 Ghz speed

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, asus-laptop, clockspeed

I am having troubles with this laptop it runs very slow at `0.75 Ghz`.

Windows 10 64bit with all drivers updated.

The power plan of Windows already been set to 100% for both minimum and maximum processor speed.

After a lot of researching the problem seems to be caused by `PROCHOT` CPU flag which is weird to see it enabled by default. The problem here is that i cannot disable it through BIOS there is no option for that.

The temporary solution I have found is to use ThrottleStop software to disable it, and then everything goes back to normal again. CPU clock speed jumps back to `2.00 Ghz`, but then it goes back to it's low speed at next reboot.

Is there any solution to this issue? Some said that it could be a faulty sensor on the board. Any suggestions?

Comment: PROC HOT gets enabled when your CPU exceeds max temp. Maybe fan has failed and the CPU is frying? Disabling throttling doesn't seem safe. Sensor is built inside the CPU, not on the board.

Comment: Forgot to mention that CPU temp is quite normal. ~45 C for all of the cores.

Comment: "I am having troubles with this laptop it runs very slow at 0.75 Ghz." - How have you determined this exactly?

Comment: From task manager i was checking CPU load then on performance tab i saw it.

Comment: reset the power plan in control->panel->power options to the default values and look what happens